# Entity framework pipeline

Tags: entity-framework

I am looking for resources that details the query execution pipeline in EF?Like how the linq query is converted into Expression tree and how the tree is converted into SQl. How EF looks into the query cache ,loading edmx metadata etc? I am trying to understand the framework better rather than just understanding the APIs.

Comment: What did you find so far and in what way did it not offer enough?